# Gson parse response to get generic class

Tags: java, json, api, apache-httpclient-4.x

I've a response class

```
public class ResponseModel<T> {
    private boolean isRequestSuccessful;

    public boolean getIsRequestSuccessful() {
        return this.isRequestSuccessful;
    }

    public void setIsRequestSuccessful(boolean isRequestSuccessful) {
        this.isRequestSuccessful = isRequestSuccessful;
    }

    private String message;

    public String getMessage() {
        return this.message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    private T object;

    public T getObject() {
        return this.object;
    }

    public void setObject(T object) {
        this.object = object;
    }
}
```

My API will return type T. I would like to parse the response from the API and create a object of type ResponseModel.

I am trying to achieve something like below which I can do it easily with c#. Please help on how to do this with Java

```
public static ResponseModel<T> Get(String requestUri) throws ClientProtocolException,IOException {
    CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(requestUri);
    httpGet.addHeader("TenantKey", TenantKey);
    httpGet.addHeader("accept", "application/json");
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);

    ResponseModel<T> responseModel = new ResponseModel<T>();

    if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200) {
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
        // parse the response as T and and assign to object of ResponseModel 
        responseModel.object = ...
    }
    else
    {
        responseModel.message = response.getEntity().getContent();
    }
// return ResponseModel here
}
```

Comment: Please consider giving some feedback, maybe upvotes/accepts at some point.

Comment: @GhostCat Sorry for the delay, I updated the question with what I ended up

Comment: When you got enough content for a good self-answer, then simply write one, and accept it. Putting the solution into the question itself isn't a good way of dealing with that.

Comment: @GhostCat Done. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of other answers and further searching in Google, I ended up with the following code

```
public static <T> ResponseModel<T> Get(Class<?> classType, String requestUri) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException 
{
    CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(requestUri);
    httpGet.addHeader("accept", "application/json");
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
    ResponseModel<T> responseModel = new ResponseModel<T>();
    if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200) 
    {
        responseModel.setObject((T) Utils.fromJson(EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()), classType));
        responseModel.setIsRequestSuccessful(true);
    } 
    else 
    {
        responseModel.setMessage(response.getEntity().getContent().toString());
        responseModel.setIsRequestSuccessful(false);
    }
    return responseModel;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Generics in C# and Java are pretty different. Simply spoken, there is no sense in what you are doing here.

The java generic T you are using there is a *compile* time feature. It allows you to use more specific types at *compile* time, instead of using `Object` all over the place.

Therefore you can't use generics to determine a "T" at "runtime", as you probably intend to. That T in your method comes from the "outside", and the *compiler* determines that in occasion it should be a `ResponseModel<Integer>` and `ResponseModel<Whatever>` in another context.

You can't have gson read JSON data to return a specific `ResponseModel<Whatever>` for you. If at all, you might be able to use [TypeAdapter magic](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/TypeAdapter.html) that does some switching based on the actual value, to return this or that **specific** `ResponseModel<Foo>`.

Beyond that: when using such *bean like* classes as your ResponseModel, you simply want them to be **specific**, not generic.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but I had a similar requirement, but its for Android though. Here is the reference link, where I had to write a generic class to load the different forms of JSON from Assets folder and parse to POJO class.

https://github.com/gokulnathperiasamy/Android-Helper/blob/master/JSONHelper.java

Code:

```
    private static String convertJSONtoEntity(String jsonString, String typeString) {
        String jsonObjectString = null;
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
            jsonObjectString = jsonObject.get(typeString).toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
        return jsonObjectString;
    }

    private static <T> List<T> fromJsonList(String json, Class<T> clazz) {
        Object[] array = (Object[]) java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(clazz, 0);
        array = new Gson().fromJson(json, array.getClass());
        List<T> list = new ArrayList<>();
        if (array != null && array.length > 0) {
            for (Object anArray : array) {
                list.add(clazz.cast(anArray));
            }
        }
        return list;
    }
```

Usage:

Invoke `convertJSONtoEntity()` with your `jsonString` and `typeString` will be your root element of your JSON.

Invoke the `fromJsonList()` with value returned by `convertJSONtoEntity()` and `Class`. This gives list of objects from JSON.